# Clear Shared Preference if app remain ideal without any operation on Same Fragment or Activity

Tags: android, session, jwt, sharedpreferences

I am using `SharedPreference` for storing session `Token` for Authenticated request.The requirement is I need to clear preference and remove Token from Preference, If user stays for long time on same `Fragment` or `Activity`. Also, many of times when I perform some operations and need to `POST` or `GET` request to server then I am able to identify whether session is expired or not.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to clear a shared preference and set timer. Lets say 5 minutes:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(“token", 0);// 0 is your mode, in this case MODE.PRIVATE
prefs.edit().remove("token").commit();
  }
}, 5*60*1000);
```

Comment: I want to clear shared preference only when user don't perform any operation like navigating to other fragment or button click etc

Comment: Then you should reset your timer on all your listeners, such as onClickListener(). Put this in a function with a timer.cancel at the beginning and call it everytime you want